# Error at "placement new: explicit construct"

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I'm following Stroustroup's example on using implicit unions.

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class MemoryObject {
public:
    enum class t { STRING, BOOLEAN };
    t type;

    MemoryObject& operator=(const MemoryObject& s) {
        if (type == t::STRING && s.type == t::STRING) {
            str = s.str;
            return *this;
        }

        if (type == t::STRING) str.~string();
        type = s.type;

        switch (s.type) {
            case t::BOOLEAN:
                boolean = s.boolean;
                break;
            case t::STRING:
                new(&str){s.str};
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return *this;
    }

private:
    union {
        unsigned long boolean;
        string str;
    };
    t stored;
};
```

On the other hand, I get the following errors over the invocation of the explicit construct:

> /mnt/DEC4763AC47614CD/Progetti/object_converter/MemoryObject.h:30:27:
>
> error: ‘s’ does not name a type
>
> ```
>     new(&str)(s.str);
>               ^ /mnt/DEC4763AC47614CD/Progetti/object_converter/MemoryObject.h:30:28:
> ```
>
> error: expected ‘)’ before ‘.’ token
>
> ```
>     new(&str)(s.str);
>                ^
> ```

As a side question, I'm also wondering why I must explicitely use the `using namespace std;` in order to call the explicit destroy `str.~string();` while, on the other hand, it is possible to write neither `str.~std::string();` nor `str.std::~string();`. I'm using the following compiler: `g++ (Ubuntu 6.3.0-12ubuntu2) 6.3.0 20170406`

Comment: A typo? It should be `new(&str) string(s.str);`.

Comment: Regarding the namespacing: Dr Stroustrup has a particular teaching model for C++ in mind in which there is a "beginner's mode", where you tell people to include a few opaque lines at the top of the file and then get a simpler language. In that approach, you don't teach namespaces in the beginning, so `using namespace std;` becomes part of the "opaque noise" at the top. Other parts of this preamble are custom headers like `#include "std.h"`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, I suppose it is a book typo (I'm using "The C++ Programming Language", Fourth Edition). That fix did the trick. On the other hand, I thought that that was just a syntactic sugar I wasn't aware of.

Comment: @KerrekSB no problem with that, I'm wondering how I can call the explicit distructor without using the namespace.

Comment: @jackb: Try `str.~basic_string()`?

Comment: Great, that answered to my other question. Thanks